# Mercator. What are the base points when displaying the whole world?

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap, mercator

Maybe someone knows exactly what are the base points when displaying the whole world on the Mercator projection? For example, in OpenStreetMap or GoogleMap.

I am referring to the following points (I have also given the suggested values):

[image]

The fact is that with such base points, the aspect ratio is equal to 1.0032865959001496.
This is close to a square, but it still seems to me rather inaccurate ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand the exact question but the more accurate max/min latitudes are:

- *Web map tile service latitude limit is +/- 85.05112878°* per https://epsg.org/crs_3857/WGS-84-Pseudo-Mercator.html (click "EXTENT" for details)
- or slightly rounded 85.051129 as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator_projection#Formulas